# Change multiple full-stop separated sentences in a sentence to Sentence case

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I want to convert multiple texts in a sentence to sentence case that includes a full-stop. For example,

> this is a Sentence case. this is also a sentence case.

should be

> This is a sentence case. This is also a sentence case.

Got this formula from a forum  `=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))&LOWER(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))` but it considers only the first statement.

Could you please help out using a custom formula or maybe VBA macro

Comment: This is quit confusing,,, better you [Edit] the post and add some real sample data the reason is simple if the cell has many sentences then which FULL STOP should considered for Sentence Case !!

Comment: @RajeshS the question is clear for me. All sentences should have sentence case.

Comment: Edited the post. No matter how many full-stops but the following sentence should be in sentence case. The formula I posted considers only the first one whereas it should consider all those which follow a full-stop. Another example - "plan A. plan B. Plan c." should be "Plan a. Plan b. Plan c."

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Yes exactly

Comment: @Irvin,, then please modify the Title of the question ,, and i think better should be `Change into sentence case` .

Comment: @RajeshS: Done.

Comment: @Irvin,, now check my post I've solved it.

Comment: If it's just a one-time or infrequent usage, it might be easier to just copy-paste into Word, hit `Shift + F3`, then copy-paste back?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Answer (score 2):

*Let me first explain the reason, that why your formula in not working.*

`=UPPER(LEFT(A1,1))&LOWER(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1))`

It's only converts 1st letter of `A1` to *Upper case*, and applies *Lower case* on rest of `A1`.

This issue needs something tricky formula.

[image]

- Formula in Cell `Q4`:

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER (SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(Q1),". ","9z9")," ","zxz")),"9Z9",". "),"zxz"," ")
  ```

*Actually, the formula replaces full stops/periods and also the blanks, with 3 character strings to apply the trick, the `PROPER` case, considers every sentence like a word. After that formula re-substitutes the text with full stops/periods & blanks.*

**N.B.**

- Copy the formula in Cell `Q8` & `Q12` also.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: This solution seems to have some issues:  `now is the time for all good men to Come to the aid of the party.  the Quick Brown fox jumped over the lazy Dog's Back.` --> `Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party. Zxzthe quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'S back.`  There is a superfluous `Zxz` in the result.  And the letter after an apostrophe is capitalized. The first seems to be an issue with more than one space after the `dot`.  Suggest using `TRIM` to remove that. Not sure about the post-apostrophe capitalization.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld,, nice observation,, what I found only issue with the `apostrophe is capitalized`,, let me find out to fix it,,TRIM doesn't makes any difference,, thanks.

Comment: To reproduce the first problem, you must ensure there is **more than one** `space` after the `Dot`.  The page editor apparently removed the extra space from the example in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 or Excel 2016 with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **array** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(". ",TRUE,UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(LOWER(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A4,".",REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999)))))& MID(TRIM(LOWER(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A4,".",REPT(" ",999)),seq_999,999))),2,999))
```

where `seq_999` is a **named formula** that returns an array that looks like `={1;999;1998;2997;3996;...` and refers to:

```
=IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*999)
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

**Algorithm**

- Make all letters lower case.
- Replace the `Dot` with `999 spaces`
- Using mid and the seq_999 array, split the string into the separate sentences based on the `Dot`.
- `TRIM` the resultant array to get rid of leading/trailing spaces.
- Replace the first letter with it's upper case equivalent.

[image]